# Flutter: Continuously running stopwatch when switching screens

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, widget, stopwatch

I have a `stopwatch` widget which is called from the `Detailed Activity` page on one of my screens that starts when the page loads. How am I able to keep it continuously running in the background so that when I navigate from `Detailed Activity` to the `Home` page, I can display that same stopwatch's time?

At the moment, the `Home` page displays the last saved time (into the variable). Instead I would like this to continue incrementing each second and vice versa switching between the two screens. I've tried adding the `startWatch()` and `initState()` method in my `Home` page, but don't know how to pass the stopwatch value while navigating to the `Detailed Activity` page

[image]
[image]

To clarify this more, my thinking was on the `Detailed Activity` page it is at e.g. 00:15:00 -> pass it into `Home` page and call initState() to automatically start the timer again. Would this work?

**Timer.dart**

```
class NewStopWatch extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NewStopWatchState createState() => new _NewStopWatchState();
}

class _NewStopWatchState extends State<NewStopWatch> {

  static _NewStopWatchState stopwatch;
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  Timer timer;
  bool startStop = true;
  static String elapsedTime = '';
  String duration;

  updateTime(Timer timer) {
    if (watch.isRunning) {
      setState(() {
        elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(watch.elapsedMilliseconds);
        User.getCurrentUser().getCurrentActivity().setElapsedTime(elapsedTime);
      });
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(elapsedTime, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  onPressed: () => startOrStop(),
                  child: Icon(Icons.pause)),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  heroTag: "btn2",
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  onPressed: () => completeActivity(),
                  child: Icon(Icons.check)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ));
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => startWatch());
  }

  startOrStop() {
    if(startStop) {
      startWatch();
    } else {
      stopWatch();
    }
  }

  startWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = false;
      watch.start();
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTime);
    });
  }

  stopWatch() {
    setState(() {
      startStop = true;
      watch.stop();
      setTime();
    });
  }

  resetWatch() {
    watch.reset();
    setTime();
  }

  setTime() {
    var timeSoFar = watch.elapsedMilliseconds;
    setState(() {
      elapsedTime = transformMilliSeconds(timeSoFar);
    });
  }

  completeActivity() { //do I call activity.stopActivity()?
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Complete Activity?',
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      duration = elapsedTime;
                      print("Current activitiy: ${User.getCurrentUser().getCurrentActivity()}");
                      // User.getCurrentUser().completeActivity();
                      User.getCurrentUser().addPastActivity(User.getCurrentUser().getCurrentActivity());
                      User.getCurrentUser().getCurrentActivity().setStatus(ActivityStatus.completed);
                      User.getCurrentUser().setCurrentActivity(null);
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FrontPage()));
                      // Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"),);
                    },
                    child:
                        new Text('Yes', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), // this line dismisses the dialog
                    child: new Text('No', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
        ) ??
        false;
    }

  transformMilliSeconds(int milliseconds) {
    int hundreds = (milliseconds / 10).truncate();
    int seconds = (hundreds / 100).truncate();
    int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();
    int hours = (minutes / 60).truncate();

    String hoursStr = (hours % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String minutesStr = (minutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    return "$hoursStr:$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
  }

   static String getElapsedTime() {
    return elapsedTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like you should look into the bloc Pattern and bloc providers. You could create a bloc class which handles the Timer and then streams the values to all the screens which uses the stopwatch. A good introduction can be found here: http://flutterdevs.com/blog/bloc-pattern-in-flutter-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear for me if this solution will work since you posted a lot of code but it is missing the part where you actually display the NewStopWatch but I hope this solution helps:

Pass the Stopwatch and the timer as arguments in the init method of your NewStopWath class and have them passed from your main page - the page where you want them displayed as well... i suppose it is the FrontPage.

Like so:

```
class FrontPage extends StatelessWidget {
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch();
    Timer timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTime);
//... code

//.. somewhere a NewStopWatch is created 
           return NewStopWatch(watch, timer);
    }
//... code


class NewStopWatch extends StatefulWidget {

  Stopwatch watch;     
  Timer timer;

  NewStopWatch(this.watch, this.timer);

  @override
  _NewStopWatchState createState() => new _NewStopWatchState();
}


class _NewStopWatchState extends State<NewStopWatch> {

  static _NewStopWatchState stopwatch;
  bool startStop = true;
  static String elapsedTime = '';
  String duration;

  Stopwatch get watch => widget.watch;
  Timer get timer => widget.timer;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => startWatch());
  }
```

**Be sure to check if you should remove timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), updateTime); from startWatch()** 
maybe you don't need to have it passed as an argument